# How to pass value in #define directives in c?

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I want to pass value in #define directives. I am new to c programming. For example we use %s or % d in printf function printf("hello %d",into); how can I use same in # define directives.my code is #define URL "www.my website.com" I am trying to pass value using following code #define URL "my website.com%d", int but I am getting no result

Comment: You mean at compile-time? Check your compilers manual for the correct flags.

Comment: Please do me a favor on your education - You macros for the simple stuff

Comment: My URL is "www.mywebsite.com?c=12" but I want to pass value in c=12 can I use %d like "www.my website.com?c=%d", int

Comment: Why do you want to use a macro for this? It almost sounds as if you want to use [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: Can I use # define URL(x) "my website.com?c=#x"

Comment: @R.zeiwald No, then your output will be the string as it is without substituting for x

Comment: OK I got it but what if there are two parameters? In URL  "my website.com?c=12&c2=13" then how do I pass two values to #define directives. # define URL (x,y) "my website.com?c=" #x"c2="#y

Comment: OK I will try this Zheyuan Li,thanks.thank alot

Comment: Still experimenting on this ,I think I will try this tommarow my head is spinning now I need a nap :p

Comment: How do I pass 3 and 5 then? using i and j in URL(i,j)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Macro arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define URL(i) "www.mywebsite.com"#i

int main() {
    printf(URL(5)); // Will print www.mywebsite.com5
    return 0;
}
```

`#` is called the pasting operator. It pastes two tokens together.

OR you can do this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define URL(i) "www.mywebsite.com %d", i

int main() {
    printf(URL(5));
    return 0;
}
```

### Difference:

- In the 1st solution, the pre-processor simply pastes any value of `i` with "www.mywebsite.com". It doesn't necessarily have to be data. It can be anything.
  If you pass in `URL(ABC)` (Note: `ABC` is not a string. It is without quotes. It is just a simple token.), your output will be `www.mywebsite.comABC`.
  If you pass in `URL("ABC")` ("ABC" with quotes), you output will be `www.mywebsite.com"ABC"`.
  So in short, it doesn't matter what you pass, pre-processor doesn't care about the data-type. It treats it just as a simple token and pastes it with `www.mywebsite.com`. Here your `"ABC"` wasn't treated as a String by pre-processor but as any other token.
- In the 2nd solution, the pre-processor doesn't do any pasting. It simply evaluates your `printf` statement as, `printf("www.mywebsite.com%d", i)`. So you will need to pass in an integer as `URL(5)` or any other integer apart from `5`. If you pass data of any other datatype, it will give you a warning. You can't pass `URL(ABC)`. It will give an error. Because `ABC` is not data. But if you pass `"ABC"` as a string(i.e, with quotes), it will give a warning but your code will compile and result output would be `www.mywebsite.com96882598`

Comment: @Friday Hey, I left the answer incomplete. Sorry for that. Added explaination.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aditya I got it now :)

Comment: @R.zeiwald Hey, man! Glad you understood. But I suggest you re-read the answer. I just made some clarification. And changed some more minute mistakes in my answer. And accept the answer if it satisfies you. :)